# Place image over PDF

Tags: python, pdf

How can I place an image over an existing PDF file at an specific coordinate location. The pdf represents a drawing sheet with one page. The image will be scaled. I'm checking ReportLab but can't find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Does the image always occur at the same location?

Comment: Yes, it's basically a stamp near the lower left corner.

Comment: Is the answer below sufficient? If not then what is wrong with it?

Comment: Is there any way to put an image (like png, jpg, gif) over it? At specific coordinates? Or is the only solution to smush 2 pdfs together?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/:

```
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

writer = PdfWriter()
reader = PdfReader("document1.pdf")
watermark = PdfReader("watermark.pdf")

page = reader.pages[0]
page.merge_page(watermark.pages[0])
writer.add_page(page)

# finally, write the results to disk
with open("document-output.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

I think it's like `watermark`, see the documentation for more information

Comment: Thanks it worked fine, just cheked the PdfFileReader.getPage() and PdfFileWriter.addPage() methods from docs.

Comment: It seems PyPdf is not maintained anymore, nor the announced continuator site. What other solution exists in the long run ?

Comment: Where did `page4` come from?

Comment: @lalebarde: [`PyPDF2`](https://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/) is the successor.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. The project continues with pypdf :-)

Answer (score 53):

Its been 5 years, I think these answers need some TLC. Here is a complete solution.

The following is tested with Python 2.7

Install dependencies

```
pip install reportlab 
pip install pypdf2
```

Do the magic

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# Create the watermark from an image
c = canvas.Canvas('watermark.pdf')

# Draw the image at x, y. I positioned the x,y to be where i like here
c.drawImage('test.png', 15, 720)

# Add some custom text for good measure
c.drawString(15, 720,"Hello World")
c.save()

# Get the watermark file you just created
watermark = PdfFileReader(open("watermark.pdf", "rb"))

# Get our files ready
output_file = PdfFileWriter()
input_file = PdfFileReader(open("test2.pdf", "rb"))

# Number of pages in input document
page_count = input_file.getNumPages()

# Go through all the input file pages to add a watermark to them
for page_number in range(page_count):
    print "Watermarking page {} of {}".format(page_number, page_count)
    # merge the watermark with the page
    input_page = input_file.getPage(page_number)
    input_page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
    # add page from input file to output document
    output_file.addPage(input_page)
   
# finally, write "output" to document-output.pdf
with open("document-output.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    output_file.write(outputStream)
```

References:

pypdf project page:
https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/

Reportlab docs:
http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/pdfgen.html

Reportlab complete user guide:
https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: While you're bringing the answer up to date, the [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/) library can also [watermark](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/watermark.py) in a very similar fashion, and can also go the other way -- allowing you to use pre-existing PDFs as if they were images (without rasterizing them) in PDFs that you [build with reportlab](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/rl1/platypus_pdf_template.py).  Disclaimer:  I am the pdfrw author...

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Can you use a ready-to-use answer with pdfrw? It would be super useful.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin pdfrw could benefit greatly from a watermark example that uses a png or jpeg file and adds the water mark at specific coordinates. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 14):

I combined [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/download/) and [pypdf<3.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) to insert an image directly without having to generate the PDF up front:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from StringIO import StringIO


# Using ReportLab to insert image into PDF
imgTemp = StringIO()
imgDoc = canvas.Canvas(imgTemp)

# Draw image on Canvas and save PDF in buffer
imgPath = "path/to/img.png"
imgDoc.drawImage(imgPath, 399, 760, 160, 160)    ## at (399,760) with size 160x160
imgDoc.save()

# Use PyPDF to merge the image-PDF into the template
page = PdfFileReader(file("document.pdf","rb")).getPage(0)
overlay = PdfFileReader(StringIO(imgTemp.getvalue())).getPage(0)
page.mergePage(overlay)

#Save the result
output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(page)
output.write(file("output.pdf","w"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Thx to the previous answers. My way with python3.4 and `PyPDF2<3.0.0`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from io import BytesIO
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

def gen_pdf():
    # there are 66 slides (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg...)
    path = 'slades/{0}.jpg'
    pdf = PdfFileWriter()

    for num in range(1, 67):  # for each slide
        # Using ReportLab Canvas to insert image into PDF
        imgTemp = BytesIO()
        imgDoc = canvas.Canvas(imgTemp, pagesize=A4)
        # Draw image on Canvas and save PDF in buffer
        imgDoc.drawImage(path.format(num), -25, -45)
        # x, y - start position
        # in my case -25, -45 needed
        imgDoc.save()
        # Use PyPDF to merge the image-PDF into the template
        pdf.addPage(PdfFileReader(BytesIO(imgTemp.getvalue())).getPage(0))

    pdf.write(open("output.pdf","wb"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen_pdf()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is quite easy to do with [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) without merging two PDFs:

```
import fitz

src_pdf_filename = 'source.pdf'
dst_pdf_filename = 'destination.pdf'
img_filename = 'barcode.jpg'

# http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rect/
# Set position and size according to your needs
img_rect = fitz.Rect(100, 100, 120, 120)

document = fitz.open(src_pdf_filename)

# We'll put image on first page only but you could put it elsewhere
page = document[0]
page.insertImage(img_rect, filename=img_filename)

# See http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document/#Document.save and
# http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document/#Document.saveIncr for
# additional parameters, especially if you want to overwrite existing PDF
# instead of writing new PDF
document.save(dst_pdf_filename)

document.close()
```

Comment: @j-owens - I've been having issues with the Rect constructor. It seems like the coordinates do not work correctly and you can only insert an image upside down.

Comment: The origin (0, 0) starts in the upper-left unlike some other libraries which might start in the lower-left (although I've come across a few PDFs with weird origins). I wonder if you have your y-coordinates inverted.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. Any ideas why? Looks so neat!

Comment: In newer versions of PyMuPDF, camel case has been replaced with snake case and page.insertImage should instead be page.insert_image. Adding this for others who try the above example (like I did).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def watermarks(temp, watermar,new_file):
    template = PdfFileReader(open(temp, 'rb'))
    wpdf = PdfFileReader(open(watermar, 'rb'))
    watermark = wpdf.getPage(0)

    for i in xrange(template.getNumPages()):
        page = template.getPage(i)
        page.mergePage(watermark)
        output.addPage(page)

        with open(new_file, 'wb') as f:
            output.write(f)
```