# How to detect a pattern (such as a QR code) on a scanned paper so that it can be correctly rotated/scaled/identified?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, qr-code, image-scanner

I have PDF files or JPG images that I need to print (these are formulars that will be filled in by hand), and I need that:

- after scan, the image should be rotated / scaled perfectly with Python, so that I can access to certain parts of the formular with x, y coordinates
- the scanned images should be recognized with a number ID.

**What kind of pattern should I add on the formular paper, so that a Python library (which one?) will be able to crop it / rotate it / identify it with an ID?**

I was thinking about adding a QR-code (containin a number ID) on top left of paper, and a QR-code on bottom right of the paper, or maybe also ["hirondelles"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirondelle_(imprimerie)) symbols:

[image] [image]

The QR code would be generated with [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) library:

```
import qrcode
img = qrcode.make('ID1138934')
```

and added on top the PDF with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707039/1422096).

---

Note:

- I've read the question [How to decode a QR-code image in (preferably pure) Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233351/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-image-in-preferably-pure-python), but this does not detect the QR-code on a scanned paper; it only takes a PNG containing the QR-code only as input.
- [Here is a JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiw4H.jpg), example of scanned document:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task needs the combination of two techniques:

- First step: detect the x,y coordinates of the 4 corners of each QR code. The Python library `zbar` is useful for this. The code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50436423/1422096) + the answer shows how to do it.
- Second step: now a deskewing / perspective correction / "homography" is needed. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2791902/109021) is how to do it with Python + OpenCV.

Comment: One thing I would like to point is that you will need 4 corners with sub-pixel accuracy i.e. in decimal floating points. `zbar` gives integral coordinates which is not sufficient to get a very good result for perspective correction. I found that the new `OpenCV 4.1` has similar functionality as `zbar` and it gives 4 corners in floating point. But its not as robust as `zbar`.