# How to get the x, y position of a detected QR code on an image with zbar?

Tags: python, image-processing, qr-code, zbar

I encoded the number 1639 in the two QR codes of the image below (downloadable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0FVK.jpg)). I printed it, took a photo and tried to detect it:

```
import zbar
from PIL import Image 

scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
pil = Image.open('20180520_170027_2.jpg').convert('L')
width, height = pil.size
raw = pil.tobytes()
image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)
result = scanner.scan(image)

for symbol in image:
    print symbol.data.decode(u'utf-8')     # 1639
```

It works, even if the size of the QR code is small (~1x1 cm), which is great!

**Question: how to get the x, y position of the corners of the QR codes?**

It's sure that `zbar` *has* this information internally (mandatory to be able to decode the QR code!), but how to get access to it?

Note: [here is how to install `zbar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435929/1422096) on Windows and Python 2.7

[image]

Comment: Did you try `dir(symbol)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by a hint in a comment,

```
print(symbol.location)
```

gives the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `zbar::Symbol` class in the C++ docs of zlib has the methods `get_location_x()`, `get_location_y()` and `get_location_size()`, so your intuition that this data exists underneath was right.

Coming back to Python, when reading the [documentation](https://github.com/zplab/zbar-py) of the zbar Python binding, it looks like a `position` field is available to get the location of the QR code:

```
import zbar
image = read_image_into_numpy_array(...) # whatever function you use to read an image file into a numpy array
scanner = zbar.Scanner()
results = scanner.scan(image)
for result in results:
    print(result.type, result.data, result.quality, result.position)
```

The size of the QR code is probably also available as a field in `result` (e.g. `result.size`), and you can use it to find the 3 other corners.